# Problema para depurar un pequeño proyecto en vscode

Tags: c++, json, vscode

He creado un pequeño proyecto para probar como funcionan los constructores en una clase. El programa compila todos los modulos sin problema mediante *g++ main.cpp fecha.cpp fecha.hpp -o main*. Sin embargo, a la hora de depurar el programa tengo un error recurrente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Además de varios In function main: *undefined reference to* y los distintos métodos de la clase.
He estado buscando varias horas soluciones, pero por ahora no he encontrado nada que funcione.

Este es mi codigo:

Fecha.hpp:

```
#define FECHA_HPP_

class Fecha
{
    public:

    Fecha (int dia, int mes, int anno);
    const int mostrar_dia();
    const int mostrar_mes();
    const int mostrar_anno();

    private:
    
    int d,m,a;
};

#endif
```

Fecha.cpp

```
#include "fecha.hpp"

Fecha::Fecha(int dia, int mes, int anno) 
{

    if (d > 5)
    {
        d = 1;
    }
    
    
    m = mes;
    a = anno;

};

const int Fecha::mostrar_dia()
{
    return d;
};

const int Fecha::mostrar_mes()
{
    return m;
};

const int Fecha::mostrar_anno()
{
    return a;
};
```

Main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "fecha.hpp"

int main()
{
    int dia,mes,anno;
   Fecha fech(14,7,2001);
    dia = fech.mostrar_dia();
    mes = fech.mostrar_mes();
    anno = fech.mostrar_anno();

    std::cout << dia <<"," << mes << "," << anno << std::endl;
    
}
```

Y este es mi launch.json:

```
"version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++.exe - Compilar y depurar el archivo activo",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Habilitar la impresión con sangría para gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe compilar archivo activo"
        }
    ]
}
```

¿Alguna idea de cuál puede ser la solución?